# Enumerated text and formula with background color

Tags: color, highlighting, backgrounds

I want to have an enumeration with text and formulas with a background color, but `\colorbox` does not work, here's my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{shadethm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\definecolor{usethiscolorhere}{rgb}{0.86666,0.78431,0.78431}


\begin{document}
%\colorbox{usethiscolorhere}{
\begin{enumerate}
\item bla bla
\item bla bla
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]\lim _{x \rightarrow -\infty}F(x)=0 \end{aligned}$ and $\begin{aligned}[t]lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} F(x)=1\end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
%}
\end{document}
```

The color should be one of my self defined colors.

Answer (score 7):

You need to avoid the indentation and also to take into account the padding of `\colorbox`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\definecolor{usethiscolorhere}{rgb}{0.86666,0.78431,0.78431}

\begin{document}
\noindent\colorbox{usethiscolorhere}{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
\begin{enumerate}
\item bla bla
\item bla bla
\item $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty}F(x)=0$ and 
  $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} F(x)=1$
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

Note the two `%` characters for avoiding spurious spaces in the output and `\limits` to get the subscript underneath "lim".

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The reason the `\colorbox` command isn't working is that it expects to work on a box; the `enumerate` environment is not in a box, so you can fix it by either using (for example) a `vbox` or a `minipage`

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\definecolor{usethiscolorhere}{rgb}{0.86666,0.78431,0.78431}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{usethiscolorhere}{
\vbox{
\begin{enumerate}
\item bla bla
\item bla bla
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]\lim _{x \rightarrow -\infty}F(x)=0 \end{aligned}$ and $\begin{aligned}[t]lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} F(x)=1\end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
}
}
\end{document}
```

Comments

- I noticed you were loading the `shadethm` package. I'm not sure what the 'official' recommendation is, but personally I consider this package obsolete in favour of the significantly more powerful `mdframed` package. The `shadethm` has lots of limitations that `mdframed` does not
- Rather than using a `colorbox` for this kind of colouring, I would use the `mdframed` to define an environment for it- a complete MWE follows for your reference

**`mdframed` example**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\definecolor{usethiscolorhere}{rgb}{0.86666,0.78431,0.78431}

\newmdenv[backgroundcolor=usethiscolorhere]{myframedenv}

\begin{document}

\begin{myframedenv}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item bla bla
    \item bla bla
    \item $\begin{aligned}[t]\lim _{x \rightarrow -\infty}F(x)=0 \end{aligned}$ and $\begin{aligned}[t]lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} F(x)=1\end{aligned}$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{myframedenv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want rounded corners, then you can use something like

```
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\definecolor{usethiscolorhere}{rgb}{0.86666,0.78431,0.78431}

\newmdenv[backgroundcolor=usethiscolorhere,
          roundcorner=10pt,
          linecolor=blue,
          ]{myframedenv}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: @Germnaon you're welcome :) if the answer has helped, please remember to upvote it using the up arrow. If it has resolved the problem, please consider accepting the answer using the green check mark

Comment: ok, well I like the third possibilty more, but then I get the error message: ! LaTeX Error: File `hf-tikz.sty' not found.

or could you tell me, how can I get this colored edge into my myframedenv? Thanks!

Comment: @Germnaon I think you posted on the wrong answer

Comment: ok, I got \newmdenv[backgroundcolor=thiscolorhere,linecolor=blue]{myframedenv} but how can I get those round edges/corners ?

Comment: @Germnaon I've made an update for rounded corners- see the documentation for other examples `texdoc mdframed`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4663/discussion-between-cmhughes-and-germnaon)

Answer (score 5):

Another approach can be the [`hf-tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hf-tikz) package (two compilation runs are necessary).

Here are some examples:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}

\definecolor{usethiscolorhere}{rgb}{0.86666,0.78431,0.78431}
\hfsetfillcolor{usethiscolorhere}

\begin{document}
First possibility:
\begin{enumerate}
\item bla bla
\item bla bla
\item \tikzmarkin{first}(0.05,-0.3)(-0.05,0.4)$\begin{aligned}[t]\lim _{x \rightarrow -\infty}F(x)=0 \end{aligned}$\tikzmarkend{first} and \tikzmarkin{second}(0.05,-0.3)(-0.05,0.4)$\begin{aligned}[t]\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} F(x)=1\end{aligned}$\tikzmarkend{second}
\end{enumerate}

Second possibilty:
\begin{enumerate}
\item \tikzmarkin{enumerate}(0.05,-0.3)(-0.05,0.4)bla bla
\item bla bla
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]\lim _{x \rightarrow -\infty}F(x)=0 \end{aligned}$ and $\begin{aligned}[t]lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} F(x)=1\end{aligned}$\tikzmarkend{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Third possibility:

\tikzmarkin{whole enumerate}(0.05,-0.4)(-0.3,0)
\begin{enumerate}
\item bla bla
\item bla bla
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]\lim _{x \rightarrow -\infty}F(x)=0 \end{aligned}$ and $\begin{aligned}[t]lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} F(x)=1\end{aligned}$\tikzmarkend{whole enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: mh, wait one more problem: I compiled it twice and I get the error message: ! LaTeX Error: File `hf-tikz.sty' not found.

Comment: This is probably due to the fact that the package is quite recent: I think you should update your distribution.

Comment: could you tell me how to get that edge into the solution cmhuges told me? With the mdframed stuff? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the rounded corners?

Comment: also yes, both, the pink color and the round corners

Comment: If you are interested, the definition of the border color I used is: `\definecolor{fancyviolet}{RGB}{197,122,197}`.